# JSON data contains special characters thus invalid variable in public class

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-c#-sdk

im trying to deserialize the JSON data Ive retrieved from facebook but c# wont allow it because "F.18-24" is an invalid variable when I try to declare it in the public class. I managed to deserialize the 'metric' field but for "F.18-24" field, Im  not sure how do I go about this. Any help would be appreciated. Is it something to do with [Ext.data.Record](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Record-create) in order for the c# to read F.18-24?

My JSON data Ive retrieved from facebook:

```
{"data":[
{
    "metric":"page_fans_gender_age", 
    "value":
        {"F.18-24":19,
        "M.18-24":14,
        "M.25-34":4,
        "F.13-17":1,
        "M.13-17":1
}}]}
```

And my codes to deserialize:

```
//geting isights data age & gender
    private void kryptonButton1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

          var client = new FacebookClient(myToken.Default.token);
          var query = string.Format("SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=132414626916208 AND metric='page_fans_gender_age' AND period = period('lifetime') AND end_time = end_time_date('2013-01-18')");

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.q = query;
            dynamic results = client.Get("/fql", parameters);

            JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            String jsondata = String.Empty;
            jsondata = results.ToString();

            genderAgeDataII converted = sr.Deserialize<genderAgeDataII>(jsondata);
            Console.WriteLine(converted);
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }


}

//class for JSON Deserialize
public class genderAgeDataII
{
    public genderAgeData[] data { get; set; }
}

public class genderAgeData
{
    public string metric { get; set; }
    public genderAge value { get; set; }
}

public class genderAge
{
    //public string numbers { get; set; }
    /*string f1824 = "F.18-24";
    string m1824 = "M.18-24";
    string m2534 = "M.25-34";
    string f1317 = "F.13-17";
    string m1317 = "M.13-17"; */

    public int f1824 { get; set; }
    public int m1824 { get; set; }
    public int m2534 { get; set; }
    public int f1317 { get; set; }
    public int m1317 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB C# SDK supports generics. You can use it as

```
var data = fb.Get<genderAgeDataII>("fql", parameters);
```

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/pull/203

Then use data contracts and datamember

```
[DataContract]
public class genderAge
{
    //public string numbers { get; set; }
    /*string f1824 = "F.18-24";
    string m1824 = "M.18-24";
    string m2534 = "M.25-34";
    string f1317 = "F.13-17";
    string m1317 = "M.13-17"; */

    [DataMember(Name="F.18-24")]
    public int f1824 { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

Comment: gosh I am a fan of your splendid facebook c# blog!  thank you very much!!! this solves my problem! =D